# Kibana DSL or query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a field in Kibana called **test**. How can I write a DSL query that finds documents where the value for **test** is either "one two three" or "four five six"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [bool/should](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause with the [match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "test": "one two three"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "test": "four five six"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

OR you can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) on the `test.keyword` field

```
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "test.keyword": [
                "one two three",
                "four five six"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```